# Which areas of my computor are at risk if I set up MySQL on port 3306 unencrypted?

Tags: databases, mysql

Does this just put the MySQL data at risk or pose a risk to my whole computer as well?

I'm using my personal device and setting up MySQL as I seem to need it to use Wordpress on my device.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a port means that other devices can communicate with your computer on that port, assuming there's a program listening on that port.  It's extremely likely MySQL will be the only thing that ever listens on port 3306 on your computer.

Generally speaking, you are correct that it will only allow an attacker to (potentially) access your MySQL data.  However, if the user they've gotten access to has sufficient permissions, they can [directly run arbitrary shell commands on your computer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/929342/120999).  Additionally, there are periodically vulnerabilities found in MySQL that could allow an attacker to run shell commands even without this permission.

However, backing up a bit, if you're running Wordpress and MySQL on the same computer, you don't need to open up the port at all.

In short:

1. Restrict access to the port to only the one computer running Wordpress.
2. Give your MySQL user accounts the minimum required permissions.
3. Keep MySQL up to date.